# '..' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. (lite-server)

Tags: npm, truffle, npm-live-server

I am following this [truffle pet-shop tutorial](https://trufflesuite.com/tutorial/index.html)

When i try `npm run dev` i get the following error message:

```
> pet-shop@1.0.0 dev
> ../../../Desktop/BlockchainTechnology/pet-shop-tutorial/node_modules/.bin/lite-server

'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The folder is not located in `Desktop`.
I have already tried `npm install lite-server@2.3 --save-dev`
I downloaded the project from a friends git, the .gitignore only includes `node_modules/`

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file content?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

The package.json files run script had stored the local path from my friends computer.

So i changes from:.

```js
run : '../../Desktop/project/node_modules/lite_server'
```

to

```js
run : 'lite_server'
```